# Using GraphViz in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml, graphviz

I want to use GraphViz in my WPF application without installing Graphviz.

Does AT&T (or somebody else) distribute such a DLL?

Thanks,
Kemal

Answer (score 3):

You can compile the dot tool as DLL from source. That is what I did a while back. I use QuickGraph with GraphViz and render the graph with slightly modified version of the control you can get from here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Dot2Wpf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Apparently ImageMagick can read the graphviz DOT format: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Perhaps you can call ImageMagick from .NET using this wrapper http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/ and get it to read DOT and output as PNG or something? I've never tried, and for all I know ImageMagick might end up spawning the command line program anyway!

(I have used graphviz from ASP classic a long time ago by spawning the graphviz executable with good results BTW.)

Answer (score 1):

Try graphviz library .NET wrapper http://code.google.com/p/graphviznet/.

It accepts the description of a graph in the form of managed objects, runs through the graphviz layout engine and gets back the data.

If you don't want't to install complete graphviz, you can copy only required set of dll's, see readme.txt in demo project, project also contains a WPF control to display graphs.

Answer (score 0):

**Licensing**

GraphViz is licensed under the Common Public License (see [the CPL FAQ](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-cplfaq.html))

Also from the GraphViz site:

> For more information on the Common
> Public License, see the FAQ. If you
> have any concerns about the what the
> license means, especially if money is
> involved, you should contact an
> intellectual property lawyer.

**Using GraphViz as a DLL**

GraphViz is an executable program rather than a DLL - to use it in your app you need to spawn the executable with the correct command line parameters and pick up the resulting output.

**Other ways of using GraphViz**

There is a COM component available that parses the DOT language and renders it:
[WinGraphViz](http://wingraphviz.sourceforge.net/wingraphviz/) but I've never used it and cannot vouch for how well it works.

Aside: If you are doing graph work in WPF I thoroughly recommend using QuickGraph to actually manage the graph - it will also output to GraphViz compatible text files.

Comment: OK but is it at all technichally possible?

Comment: See edits - it's possible but you need to launch an .exe rather than using it like a library

Comment: Why?
Why not use it as a library if it is possible (as you say)?

Comment: It is available only as a .EXE - it is not possible to use this as a library. My original meaning was that it is possible to use GraphViz from a WPF application but you must spawn the .exe to do the work

Comment: So nobody ever compiled a DLL out of it?

Comment: There are several DLLs in the installation which you might be able to use if you can program in C++ but I've never seen a single DLL version of GraphViz.

Comment: WinGraphViz was dead long ago.

And QuickGraph is a general purpose graph library that uses GraphViz only as one of the possible back-ends.

Comment: I know this comment is rather late, but you can definitely use Graphviz as a library. They even have a guide on their website: http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf. If you just want to layout and render a graph, you'll need graph.dll, gvc.gll, cdt.dll, ltdl.dll, zlib1.dll, and pathplan.dll from the /bin directory along with the associated .lib and .h files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fairly new object-oriented Graphviz wrapper for .NET: https://github.com/Rubjerg/Graphviz.NetWrapper

Since it works by doing foreign function calls to the Graphviz library it ships with, you don't have to install anything.